# Callback function documentation in NodeJS, especially net.createServer

Tags: node.js, sockets, callback

[The NodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener) writes that `net.createServer` has an optional argument `connectionListener`

```
net.createServer([options][, connectionListener])
```

The documentation does not tell that it has an argument, the incoming connection's socket, it turns out only from the example code:

```
const net = require('net');
const server = net.createServer((c) => {
  // 'connection' listener
  console.log('client connected');
  c.on('end', () => {
    console.log('client disconnected');
  });
  c.write('hello\r\n');
  c.pipe(c);
});
server.on('error', (err) => {
  throw err;
});
server.listen(8124, () => {
  console.log('server bound');
});
```

Where is it documented in the NodeJS documentation whether a callback function has any arguments and what are those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is documented as the parameter passed to the 'connection' event:

> - `connectionListener`  Automatically set as a listener for the **'[connection](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/net.html#net_event_connection)'** event.

And if you check what the **connection** event is you will get this:

> ## Event: 'connection'
>
> Added in: v0.1.90
>
> - `<net.Socket>` The connection object
>
> Emitted when a new connection is made. socket is an instance of net.Socket.

So the parameter passed to a function that handles the **connection** event is a [net.Socket](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket) object.